# Inspect object to get the entire composite object it belongs to

Tags: python, composite

Say I have nested `pydantic.BaseModel`(s) (but my question is not class specific). At one point, I am calling a method by providing `conf.compta.fec` as argument. `conf` is a composite BaseModel, attributes of which are also BaseModels (at least *compta* and *fec*)

```
PathAssembler.generate_abfss_uri("SomeTable", conf.compta.fec, "container")
```

From the stand point of the function, I would like to be able to identify the entire `conf.compta.fec` chain by inspecting `model`. In other words, I would like to get all the classes `model` is recursively an attribute of

```py
class PathAssembler:
    @classmethod
    def generate_abfss_uri(cls, table_name: str, model: BaseModel, container_name: str, delta=True):
        # HERE: how to get the classes `model` is the composite of ?
        return f"abfss://{container_name}//{table_name}{'.delta' if delta else ''}"
```

How can I achieve this? Could `inspect be of any help?